# can't connect to websocket (Mixed Content)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

so i was trying to make web socket server

node js

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
var porth = process.env.PORT || 80;
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port:porth})

wss.on("connection", ws => {
    console.log("nowe połączenie");
    ws.on("message",  data => {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
    ws.send("hej");
    ws.on("close", () =>
    {
        console.log("rozłączenie");
    });
})
```

app.js

```
ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
  console.log("połączono")
  ws.send("test");
  ws.addEventListener("message", data => {
    console.log(data.data)
  })
})
```

and when i host it on my pc it works but
when i upload it to github pages it keeps
sending me error:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://*****.github.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://****.herokuapp.com/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

and i dont know what should i do about it

Answer (score 0):

So from this error I assume that you are connecting between secure and not secure site. I'm not sure but if I can I would suggest you to see ws https server. Maybe this will help https://github.com/websockets/ws#external-https-server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).